# Uninstall on android wear

Tags: uninstallation, android-wear

I have an android wear device and I'd like to uninstall apps with sideload.

I already have:

```
1 adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub 
2 adb connect localhost:4444 
3 adb devices 
4 adb -s localhost:4444 shell 
5. pm list packages 
6 adb uninstall [package name]
```

but there is then -waiting for device-

does anyone know how I can solve this problem or how I can uninstall apps another way with side load?

thanks

Comment: We're going to move this question over to the Android StackExchange site where it'll find a community more knowledgeable in this area.

Answer (score 2):

Your instructions are almost correct. The one thing you need to remember is that the command you specified in step 4, namely `adb -s localhost: 4444`, is to be repeated each time you wish to perform some kind of action towards the Wear device.

Therefore, you simply change step 6 to `adb -s localhost: 4444 uninstall [package_name]`

Bear in mind that step 5 will produce packages that look something like `package:com.google.android.music`. Be sure that, in step 5, you simply put `com.google.android.music` where `[package_name]` should be.

Hope this helps! More information [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html#debug).